# How can I make this query in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have theese fields(`test_type, status, begin_time, and_time`).The `status` field has three state(`0`, `1` or `2`). 
I want to make a queryset where:

```
(test_type = 'difficult') and 
(if status=1 and begin_time + 2x(end_time - begin_time) < timezone.now()) or
(if status=2 and end_time < timezone.now())
```

then select theese fields. If the status state=0 I dont want to select that field.
How can i make this queryset with Django ORM?

Comment: status==1 and status==2 returns False. 
test_type = 'difficult') has no open brasket and = instead of ==.
Can you check your expression?

Comment: I have corrected from And to OR

Comment: Can you share your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work. You need to create the annotation for "twice_end_time" as Django doesn't support that kind of calculation in filters

```
Model.objects.annotate(
    twice_end_time=F('begin_time') + 2 * F('end_time') - F('begin_time')
).filter(
    Q(test_type='difficult') &
    Q(status=1, twice_end_time__lt=timezone.now()) |
    Q(status=2, end_time__lt=timezone.now())
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the Q object in Django,

```
Model.objects.filter((Q(status=1) & Q(begin_time < computed_value_here)) | (Q(status=2) & Q(end_time < computed_value_here)), test_type='difficult')
```